# How to make a XML of a list with python?

Tags: python, xml, list

I only want to make a XML with the elements of the list but seem to work pretty bad making a blank XML i need help

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,"final"]

for i in range(len(lista)):

    if i == 0 :
        root = ET.Element("{}".format(lista[i]))
    else:
        doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")
        nodo1 = ET.SubElement(doc, "nodo")

ET.SubElement(doc, "nodo")

arbol = ET.ElementTree(root)

arbol.write("path")
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you want to resulting XML to look like?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you are looking for as a result, but your code produces an xml file with content...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, here is how you can achieve something like this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,"final"]

for i in range(len(lista)):
    # set up a specific attribute based on the content of lista
    attrib = dict(lista=str(lista[i]))

    if i == 0 :
        root = ET.Element("{}".format(lista[i]), attrib)
        prior = root
    else:
        prior = ET.SubElement(prior, "doc", attrib)

ET.SubElement(prior, "nodo")
ET.SubElement(prior, "nodo")

arbol = ET.ElementTree(root)
arbol.write('./result.xml')
```

The trick is to store the subelement of the last iteration in prior, create the next subelement as a child of prior and again set this element as prior.

result.xml:

```
<1 lista="1">
    <doc lista="2">
        <doc lista="3">
            <doc lista="4">
                <doc lista="5">
                    <doc lista="6">
                        <doc lista="7">
                            <doc lista="final">
                                <nodo />
                                <nodo />
                            </doc>
                        </doc>
                    </doc>
                </doc>
            </doc>
        </doc>
    </doc>
</1>
```

Comment: well, i would like something more like this

Comment: <1 lista="1">
    <doc lista="2">
     <doc lista="3">
         <doc lista="4">
          <doc lista="5">
    <doc lista="6">
     <doc lista="7">
      <doc lista="final">
             <nodo />
            <nodo />
       </doc>
   </doc>
  </doc>
 </doc>
    </doc>
</1>

Comment: Thank you dude i was waste a lot of time thinking in a way of doing this i really apreciate for your help

Comment: Glad I could help. Maybe upvote/accept as answer then

Comment: this is odd to ask but..how can i do that?, i´m pretty new in this site.

Comment: @TonyUM Clicking the arrow next to my answer, as it appears you did already.